# Using S3 as nutch storage system

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, nutch

I want to use S3 as my file system for apache nutch. I am aware that hadoop can be configured to use S3 as its fs but I can't find a way to configure this with nutch. Can someone point me in the right direction or give me a quick rundown of the method for this. Alternatively, being able to dump data into s3 with the readseg command would be a solution rather than having the whole filesystem in s3, is this possible?

cheers

Comment: Well, how is Nutch configured to use HDFS vs your local filesystem? What steps did you take to configure it to do that? Can you do the same for S3?

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing Nutch specific to specify how to store the data. We just use whatever Hadoop provides. If Hadoop is configured to use S3 it should work transparently for Nutch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nutch when running in (pseudo-)distributed mode is proved to work with any filesystem supported by the underlying Hadoop installation, including S3 or S3A.

Please note:

- it does not work out-of-the-box when running in local mode because the required libs are not dependencies of Nutch by default. You would need to add all necessary libs as IVY managed dependencies and re-compile Nutch.
- there have been issues in previous versions of Nutch where HDFS has been hard-wired in the code. This has been fixed for 1.14, see [NUTCH-2281](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2281).
- Nutch uses a file system "mv" to atomically install the current version of CrawlDb and LinkDb. On S3 this means copying the files which is notoriously slow. It might be more efficient to keep the CrawlDb on HDFS and distcp it to S3 from time to time.
- Segments have unique names, so they can be efficiently kept on S3. But also have a look at the [documentation of S3A committers](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committer_architecture.html).

Answer (score 0):

In theory, if you add the key value for `fs.s3a.impl` and modify the core-site.xml `fs.defaultFS` to point at an S3 bucket path, then it should work. The problem isn't specifically limited to Nutch

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html